# Mapping imperative conditional statements (with exception throwing) to Reactive process

Tags: java, project-reactor

I am struggling to make sense of Reactive process flow. My understanding is that, when manipulating data within a `Mono` or `Flux`, type consistency must be maintained. However, when problems occur within that process, something resembling an exception must be thrown, and that breaks the type consistency.

Currently, I have an imperative process for taking a verification token ID and processing it. In two instances, it throws exceptions (`InvalidTokenException` is `404` response; `ExpiredTokenException` is a `410`), and in the last modifies and saves the account, and deletes the token. I would like to convert this to a reactive process:

```
public AccountDto verifyAccountByToken (UUID tokenId) {
    VerifyToken vToken = verifyTokenRepository.findByToken(tokenId);
    if (vToken == null) {
        throw new InvalidTokenException();
    }
    if (vToken.isExpired()) {
        verifyTokenRepository.delete(vToken);
        throw new ExpiredTokenException();
    }
    Account account = vToken.getAccount();
    account.addRole(AccountRole.VERIFIED);
    account.deleteRole(AccountRole.UNVERIFIED);
    accountRepository.save(account);
    verifyTokenRepository.delete(vToken);
    return new AccountDto(account);
}
```

I believe the below is essentially correct for the data-manipulation process when everything is as it should be, but how do I handle the conditional branching?  – How do I say: do-this-if-empty? (I figure I can use `.filter()` as a way of capturing the expired case.) And how do I convert it to an error type?

```
public Mono<AccountDto> verifyAccountByToken (UUID tokenId) {
    return verifyTokenRepository.findByToken(tokenId)
            
            // the bits I can't figure out to deal with Invalid and Expired tokens;
            
            .flatMap(vToken -> {
                verifyTokenRepository.delete(vToken);
                return vToken.getAccount();
            })
            .flatMap(account -> {
                account.addRole(AccountRole.VERIFIED);
                account.deleteRole(AccountRole.UNVERIFIED);
                return accountRepository.save(account);
            })
            .map(account -> new AccountDto(account));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I say: do-this-if-empty?

There's an operator for that:

```java
 .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new InvalidTokenException()));
```

Have a look at comments below:

```java
public Mono<AccountDto> verifyAccountByToken(UUID tokenId) {
  return verifyTokenRepository.findByToken(tokenId) //Mono<VerifyToken> or Mono<Void>
          .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new InvalidTokenException())); //token does not exist, empty Mono is returned, switch to an error signal
          .flatMap(this::validateToken)
          .map(vToken -> vToken.getAccount())
          .flatMap(account -> {
                //token is valid...
                account.addRole(AccountRole.VERIFIED);
                account.deleteRole(AccountRole.UNVERIFIED);
                return accountRepository.save(account);
            })
          .map(account -> new AccountDto(account));
}

private Mono<VerifyToken> validateToken(VerifyToken vToken) {
    if (vToken.isExpired()) {
        //Token is expired... delete it and then signal an error
         return verifyTokenRepository.delete(vToken) 
                  .then(Mono.error(new ExpiredTokenException()));
    }
    return Mono.just(vToken);//token is valid...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks like it will do what I want (though you dropped the conversion from `vToken` to `account` step in your solution; I'll probably include it in `validateToken()`)

Comment: @Rick I would do it after token validation. Edit made.

Comment: I changed `valitadeToken` to `redeemToken`, combining the token deletion (which was also missing), so it then made sense (I think) to handle it there, as once the token is redeemed, we have back an `Account` (which still needs to be verified).